# RNFetchBlob.mkdir got 1 arguments, expected 2

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

When i try to setup ongoing react-native project in that one of the plugin is `react-native-fetch-blob` i'll try many but can't resolve this issue.

also i remove that plugin from app and resetup all step from [npm react-native-fetch-blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch-blob)

after following all step getting same issue.

```
 `RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', 'api', {
        'Content-Type': 'application/multipart/form-data'
    }, [
        {name: 'file', filename: filename, data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(PictureURI)}

    ])
        .then((responseData) => {
          // console.log("image uploaded",responseData);
            // console.log("----------Upload Image Test---RESPONSE---------");
        })
        .catch(err => {
           // console.log(err);
           // console.log("----------Upload Image Test---RESPONSE--ERROR-------");
        })`
```

in this plugin i'm only used the fetch method but my project gives me error mkdir method.

Comment: The answer to this question is completely dependant on how you call the library. Add your code.

Comment: i'll never used mkdir method.

Comment: Question is not clear. Please elaborate.

Comment: sure please check post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Resolve this issue following steps:
react-native unlink react-native-fetch-blob
npm uninstall react-native-fetch-blob --save
yarn add react-native-fetch-blob (assuming your system already 
installed yarn)
RNFB_ANDROID_PERMISSIONS=true react-native link

then uninstall app from device/simulator/emulator and run command
react-native run-android
work perfect. 
:)
```